# Activity "jumps" when View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is set

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

I have an `Activity` for picture viewer. When I try to put it in the fullscreen mode using flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` on the root view, it doesn't just hide statusbar, it jumps and doesn't allow me to use the space behind `statusbar`.

Here's a short video of my problem: https://i.imgur.com/kKnsWL0.mp4

In the `onCreate` of my `Activity`:

```
containerView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

My toggle fullscreen function:

```
private fun toggleFullscreen() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        val fullscreenFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        if (isFullscreen) {
            containerView.systemUiVisibility = containerView.systemUiVisibility and fullscreenFlag.inv()
        } else {
            containerView.systemUiVisibility = containerView.systemUiVisibility or fullscreenFlag
        }
    }

    if (isFullscreen) {
        toolbar.visible
    } else {
        toolbar.invisible
    }

    isFullscreen = !isFullscreen
}
```

**EDIT:** looks like the problem is around the cutout, because I can see these jumps on my Google Pixel 3 XL only. Nothing wrong on Meizu PRO6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution - the reason is "notched" device. If you are facing the same problem, just put this code in your Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }
```